# Is it possible that when measured more than one Cooper pair will have tunneled across the junction?

Tags: quantum-information, superconductivity, quantum-computer, quantum-tunneling

If I've understood the idea correctly a charge qubit is formed by a superconducting island coupled by a Joseph junction to a superconducting reservoir. The state of the qubit is determined by the number of Cooper pairs that have tunneled across the junction. So an uncharged island represents the 0 state and an island with an extra Cooper pair represents the 1 state. The state of the qubit is changed via changing the voltage in the circuit. I have the following question:

Isn't it possible that when measured more than one Cooper pair will have tunneled across the junction and so a state that is neither 0 nor 1 is measured?

Comment: you will need patience as this is a specialized question and needs an answer from somebody working on this field.